# In a perfect world, should RIPE160 be used as the block ID or transaction ID?

Tags: transactions, alternatives, sha256, ripemd160

Edit: In this question I'm looking at storage advantages, and network bandwidth savings.

Given that the TxID and BlockID uses SHA256 to uniquely identify a transaction (and block) is there any reason that RIPEMD shouldn't be used in a brand new/different alt-coin?

Answer (score 1):

The malleability problem is not with the hashing function, but with what is being hashed (or not). The hashed data is malleable, not the hash directly.

Comment: I'm concerned about the storage requirements (index size, etc) rather than transaction malliability since that really doesn't apply here, as you say.

Comment: Ah i assumed wrongly... Maybe you should clarify in your question you're looking for storage advantages.